# How can I remove objects with duplicate property values while consolidating the values of another property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

*Not the same as the flagged question. I don't **just** want to delete the duplicates; I want to consolidate the values of another property of the object to be removed.

For the following object:

```
orderedGroups: [ { parent: 'Components', subgroups: [ 'alphaselector' ] },
  { parent: 'Utilities', subgroups: [ 'colors' ] },
  { parent: 'Test Group', subgroups: [ 'component-test-alpha' ] },
  { parent: 'Document', subgroups: [ 'fixedtableheaders' ] },
  { parent: 'Utilities', subgroups: [ 'svgicons' ] },
  { parent: 'Utilities', subgroups: [ 'typography' ] } ]
```

How can I remove objects with duplicate `parent` entries while consolidating the corresponding `subgroups`?

Desired output:

```
orderedGroups: [ { parent: 'Components', subgroups: [ 'alphaselector' ] },
  { parent: 'Utilities', subgroups: [ 'colors', 'svgicons', 'typography' ] },
  { parent: 'Test Group', subgroups: [ 'component-test-alpha' ] },
  { parent: 'Document', subgroups: [ 'fixedtableheaders' ] } ]
```

What I have so far/where I'm stuck:

```
for (let val of Object.values(orderedGroups)) {

  if (orderedGroups.hasOwnProperty(val.parent)) {
    // remove duplicate objects and consolidate corresponding subgroups 
  }

}
```

*Note: I cannot import modules; must be plain js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` to store subgroups by key (in this case `parent`) and then only use `for` loop to add them to `orderedGroups` as you wish.

```js
let orderedGroups = [ { parent: 'Components', subgroups: [ 'alphaselector' ] },
  { parent: 'Utilities', subgroups: [ 'colors' ] },
  { parent: 'Test Group', subgroups: [ 'component-test-alpha' ] },
  { parent: 'Document', subgroups: [ 'fixedtableheaders' ] },
  { parent: 'Utilities', subgroups: [ 'svgicons' ] },
  { parent: 'Utilities', subgroups: [ 'typography' ] } ]
  
let tmp = new Map()
for(let obj of orderedGroups) {
  if(tmp.has(obj.parent)) tmp.set(obj.parent, [...tmp.get(obj.parent), ...obj.subgroups])
  else tmp.set(obj.parent, [...obj.subgroups])
}
orderedGroups = [] 
for(let obj of tmp) {
  orderedGroups = [...orderedGroups, {parent: obj[0], subgroups: obj[1]}]
}
console.log(orderedGroups)
```

Answer (score 2):

Dominic has a more elegant solution, but here's a simpler solution that might be easier for some to understand.

```
let output = [];

for(group of orderedGroups){
  let i;
  for(i=0;i<output.length;i++){
    if(output[i].parent===group.parent) break;
  }
  if(i===output.length){
    output.push(group);
  } else {
    output[i].subgroups=output[i].subgroups.concat(group.subgroups);
  }
}
```